# web2py DAL multiple left joins

Tags: left-join, web2py

Is it possible? I tried the following:

```
rows=db().select(db.division.ALL, db.department.ALL, db.section.ALL, \
    left=db.section.on(db.department.id==db.section.department_id) & \
    db.department.on(db.division.id==db.department.division_id))
```

Error says & is not supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it as a list:

```
left=[db.section.on(db.department.id==db.section.department_id),
      db.department.on(db.division.id==db.department.division_id)]
```